# Doubt regarding Fourier series coefficients.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have some doubts while I was self studying Fourier series. I wanted to ask, there are three types of Fourier series namely; Trigonometric Fourier series, Polar Fourier series, Complex Fourier series, does complex Fourier coefficients can be found out for complex functions only? Do complex functions have non-zero Trigonometric and Polar Fourier coefficients? Do real functions have Complex Fourier coefficients? Can Trigonometric and Polar Fourier coefficients be complex numbers (with non-zero imaginary part)? Can Complex Fourier coefficients be purely real? If any answer is 'Yes', tell me when does this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Many pages would be written for answering those questions. Briefly:

Given a function $f$ with domain $\Omega$ real or complex valuated, there is only one type of Fourier series, but different perspectives for thinking on it.

> Does complex Fourier coefficients can be found out for complex functions only?

Observe $e^{inx}$ is complex valued, thus also $f(x)e^{inx}$. Then, for calculating the $n$th coefficient, we have $\int\limits_{\Omega} f(x)e^{inx} dx$ complex valuated in general. So the answer is: No. Complex coefficients also appear for real-valued functions.

> Do complex functions have non-zero Trigonometric and Polar Fourier coefficients?

Trigonometric or polar coefficients is a matter of perspective. Euler's identity $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$ translates one into the another. It is easily seen that the **modulus** corresponds to the **amplitude** of that harmonic in the function, while the the **angle** corresonds to its **phase**.

Complex functions can have some zero coefficients $b_n$ and it can be interpreted as if such function were orthogonal to the $n$th harmonic oscillator.

> Can Trigonometric and Polar Fourier coefficients be complex numbers (with non-zero imaginary part)?

Yes.

> Can Complex Fourier coefficients be purely real?

Yes, when the phase of that harmonic in the function is exactly zero.